# how to establish a listener for incoming call

Tags: c#, windows, bluetooth, 32feet

I wan t to create an application running on Windows Laptop to kind of remote control my mobile phone via Bluetooth.

I would like to:

1. establish a call on the mobile from Windows.
2. display the number of an incoming call on the mobile on Windows (and search for the related contact in Outlook).

I've just started with 32feet.net framework and was able to complete point 1 using HFP.

With the second point I'm stuck. I have read the 32feet API description but don't understand how to listen for an incoming call.
I assume I will have to use SetServiceState?

Does anyone hint me into the right direction or pass a recipe how to establish a listener?